I try to print it after using cups pdftoraster, but a format error occurs
I created a pdf file into a raster file using pdftoraster.cxx of cupsfilter.
This is my printer Epson L6290. Below are the supported mimetypes.
"application/octet-stream"
"image/pwg-raster"
"image/urf"
"image/jpeg"
"application/vnd.epson.escpr"

inPdf = fopen("test_raster_0604.tmp","wb");

if(inPdf == NULL){
  LOG("pdftoraster() inPdf == NULL");
  goto err1;
}else{
  LOG("pdftoraster() inPdf != NULL");
  inpdfdf = fileno(inPdf);
}

if ((raster = cupsRasterOpen(inpdfdf, pwgraster ? CUPS_RASTER_WRITE_PWG : CUPS_RASTER_WRITE)) == 0) {
   exit(1);
}

selectConvertFunc(raster);

for (i = 1;i <= npages;i++) {
   outPage(doc,catalog,i,out,raster);
}
cupsRasterClose(raster);
inSize = ftell(inPdf); //not 0
fclose(inPdf);

The entire code is long, so I wrote it briefly. I am attaching the URL of the code referenced below.
https://github.com/jianglei12138/cups-filters/blob/master/filter/pdftoraster.cxx#L1941
Since the raster file has been created as a file called test_raster_0604.tmp, we are now going to print the raster file using CUPS.
int nOptions = 0;

File* outRaster = fopen("/data/user/0/cache/test_raster_0604.tmp", "rb");

cupsSetEncryption(HTTP_ENCRYPTION_REQUIRED);

cups_dest_t* dest = cupsGetDestWithURI("EPSON_L6290_Series", "ipps://ip_address/ipp/print");

http_t* http = cupsConnectDest(dest, CUPS_DEST_FLAGS_DEVICE, 10000, NULL, resource, sizeof(resource), NULL, NULL);

cups_dinfo_t* pInfo = cupsCopyDestInfo(http, dest)

nOptions = cupsAddOption(CUPS_COPIES, "1", nOptions, &pOptions);
nOptions = cupsAddOption(CUPS_MEDIA, CUPS_MEDIA_A4, nOptions, &pOptions);
nOptions = cupsAddOption(CUPS_ORIENTATION, CUPS_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, nOptions, &pOptions);      

ipp_status_t status = cupsCreateDestJob(http, dest, pInfo, &nJobId, "My Document", nOptions, pOptions);


 if (cupsStartDestDocument(http, dest, pInfo, nJobId, "test_raster_0604.tmp", "image/pwg-raster", 0, NULL, 1) == HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE)
{
   while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), outRaster)) > 0)
   {
      if (cupsWriteRequestData(http, buffer, bytes) != HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE)
                    break;
   }

   LOG("Document send write done : %s", cupsLastErrorString()); ///successful-ok

   if (cupsFinishDestDocument(http, dest, pInfo) != IPP_STATUS_OK)
   {
       LOG("Document send failed: %s", cupsLastErrorString()); ///client-error-document-format-error
   }
}


I believe I have set the MimeType correctly, but a format error occurs in CUPS. Do you know the solution?

What you're saying is that you can't print with image/pwg-raster format on an Epson L6290 printer in your code now?

Actually, I run the source code of cups through JNI in Android. If you print with image/jpeg among the mimetypes above, it prints successfully, but when you use image/pwg-raster, an error client-error-document-format-error(0x411) occurs. Does the cups server not support pwg-raster?

The size of the pdf and pwg-raster was too large to be printed on the printer. If you use apache pdfbox to reduce the size of the PDF, convert it, and then print it, it will print normally.
